# Extracting unique values from a list and sorting by occurrence in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, unique, extract, formula

Is there a formula to extract all unique terms in a list in Excel, then sort them by the number of times they occurred in the list?

```
    List    Extracted Data
1   AA       AA
2   BB       CC
3   CC       BB
4   AA       EE
5   DD       DD
6   EE
7   AA
8   CC
9   CC
10  EE
11  BB
12  AA
```

AA occurs 4 times, so it is placed at the top of the extracted list, followed by CC which occurred 3 times, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the faster way is by using pivot tables:

1. Select the table (make sure there's a header; insert one if there aren't any) and go to "Insert" > "Pivot Table". You should get something like this:
   [image]
2. Click 'OK' then drag the header from the right pane once into "Row labels" and a second time into "Values":
   [image]
3. Now select column B and insert a filter through "Home" > "Sort&Filter":
   [image]
4. Now, just sort by descending:
   [image]

Comment: Hmm the problem is that my table doesn't only contain those values, but multiple other values, so I cannot group similar "AA"s together.

Comment: @user1708205 Would be great if you could provide a snapshot of your table. But if you have other columns, you can add filters on other columns if you have more (drag drop to "Report filter" and filter on only those you need).

Answer (score 1):

First use Advanced Filter to extract the unique records to column B.
Then in C1 enter:

**=COUNTIF(A$1:A$12,B1)**  and copy down

Finally sort cols B & C by C Descending

Comment: What I wish to avoid is a sheet with a lot of irrelevant data, so it'll be great if I can settle everything with one step